# Windows 8.1 x64 - V2 Credential Provider

Tags: visual-c++, dll, windows-8.1, credential-providers

I am currently trying to implement a custom credential provider on Windows 8.1. I downloaded the sample from [https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/V2-Credential-Provider-7549a730](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/). I copied the dll to C:\Windows\System32 and used the included register.reg for registering the dll. I can see all entries in the registry.

If I restart my computer I can't see any new credential providers. What do I miss? I assume that it doesn't matter whether the system is in a domain or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the dll's msvcr120.dll and msvcr120d.dll into the C:\Windows\System32 folder.

Comment: Or statically link the VS runtime

Comment: @Dani you are a life saver man, I had been beating my head around for a long time.

Comment: @Ram Thanks :-) Took me also quite a while

Answer (score 1):

did you compiled for the right bit version of your OS and as Release version? The active option in the sample is a 32bit debug version, which is not loaded, if you try it.